# Karma-typescript Interface XXX cannot simultaneously extend types ' YYY

Tags: javascript, typescript, karma-runner, karma-webpack

My `tsconfig.json` is

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "outDir": "./dist/",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "module": "es6",
    "target": "es5",
    "jsx": "react",
    "allowJs": true,
    "preserveConstEnums": true,
    "removeComments": true,
    "noImplicitAny": false,
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "noUnusedParameters": true
  },
  "include": [
    "./src/**/*"
  ],
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules",
    "@typings",
    "typings/main",
    "typings/main.d.ts",
    "typings/index.d.ts"
  ],
  "paths": {
    "react": ["node_modules/@types/react"]
  }
}
```

And I have added the `karma-typescript` to my config

```
settings.frameworks.push('karma-typescript');
settings.preprocessors['test-bundler.js'].unshift('karma-typescript');
settings.karmaTypescriptConfig = {
    tsconfig: './tsconfig.json',
};
```

Using webpack, the dev-server and compiling works fine.

And here is a dummy test

```
describe('Root', () => {
    it('should pass', () => {
        console.log('done');
    });
});
```

When running the test, I get

> node_modules/@types/react/index.d.ts(2736,19): error TS2320: Interface
>   'ElementClass' cannot simultaneously extend types 'Component' and 'Component'.   Named property 'props' of types
>   'Component' and 'Component' are not identical.

And similar to those. If I remove `settings.preprocessors['test-bundler.js'].unshift('karma-typescript');` then the test runs fine (but then I cannot pre-compile typescript when I start to import my source files.

What is going on? My normal build and dev-server run fine with the `tsconfig.json` I have

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> What is going on

You have two `react.d.ts` in the compilation context.

## Fix

Delete `node_modules` and any `package-lock` (or yarn lock) and `npm install` again.

If it doesn't work, find the invalid module (all modules should have `react.d.ts` as a `peerDependency` and not a hard `dependency`) and report it on their project.

Comment: Yes, I know `react-router` ha it's own react.d.ts. I was getting the same problem with running the `dev-server`. The fix was the use of `paths` in my `tsconfig.json`. I'm surprised that is not being respected in the test